# Scripting - Import, save, delete - Loop

Tags: python, scripting, workflow, blend-files

I'm trying to create a python script in Blender, here are the steps I want to follow:

- I have an existing scene where I want to import a specific `.blend` file from folder A.
- Once the blend file is imported, I want to save the scene as a new file with the name of the `.blend`I just imported in another folder (folder B).
- The deleted the imported `.blend`.

I want this script to loop for all the `.blend` I have in the folder A (100 files)

How can I achieve that? I'm a total noob in python scripting, so I don't know if it is possible or if it is the best approach for what I want to do...

Comment: Sounds like you want to move blend files from one folder to another, unless I don't understand your description... In that case you can use a simple python script without opening blender at all: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html

Comment: It is more like adding a blend file to a light setup and then save the whole thing in a new blend file